# Getting access to login and logout user information in ckan with a plugin

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ckan

I'm using `ckan` version 2.5.7 and I need to communicate user information from `ckan` to a rails app.  I was going to use the IAuthenticator plugin implementation but it doesn't do exactly what I need.  What I need is to send rails a message about a user logging in with their username and API key.  Then the rails app can use the information to pull catalog and other information and use it as a display, etc.

Ideally, this would happen at login and logout so the Rails app knows when the user has access and not.  The problem with the IAuthenticator interface is that it works for logouts but not logins.  The login process fires the plugin off too early and there is no user information yet.

My question is: is there another method that I could use the plugin to trigger the login and logout events and fire a message off to Rails with the information?  I was hoping to not have to modify the `ckan` base code and insert functions into the controllers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend User controller in your plugin and add the calls for rails app in login and logout functions. https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/controllers/user.py#L434